# How do I set a minimum height to my page depending on my image background

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this project, each page has a different background image for it. The images are pretty tall and not all pages have enough content to increase the height of the page. So is there a way to set a minimum height for the page depending on the height of the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is [`min-height`](http://www.css3.com/css-min-height/) css property for that.

See:

[CSS min-height Explained](http://www.search-this.com/2007/02/05/css-min-height-explained/)